# Xcode 3.1.2 locks up when loading C++ project...?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a project which builds correctly from the command line.  On one of my Macs (10.5) running Xcode 3.1.2, I can load it and build it in the Xcode IDE.  On my other Mac (same configuration of software), Xcode sometimes loads the project, but always locks up with a spinning beach ball at some point before the build is done.  Sometimes this occurs as the project is loaded, sometimes late in the build.

I've tried doing a 'clean' on the project, I've tried pulling in the source code fresh from source control.  So far, no luck -- I have to kill Xcode and in effect, cannot develop on this particular Mac.    I've uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by deleting the Xcode cache in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Xcode

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the project index (.pbxindex) from the build folder.

Comment: Yeah, I've deleted the entire build folder.  Unfortunately... no effect.  I suspect it's stuck parsing system headers for 'intellisense' or whatever they're calling their version thereof.  But Googling is proving fruitless! 

Thanks.

Comment: I finally got it to work by deleting the Xcode cache in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Xcode